# Show that every solution $G$ of the equation curl $(G) = F$ is of the form $G = G_0+\nabla f$.

Tags: vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

Let $F$ be a solenoid field, that is, div $F = 0$, in a simply connected domain $D \leq \mathbb{R}^3$ and let $G_0$ be a potential field of $F$, that is, curl $(G_0) = F$. Show that every solution $G$ of the equation curl $(G) = F$ is of the form $G = G_0+\nabla f$, where $f$ is a scalar field.

Using that div $F = 0$, I have to div curl $(G_0) = 0$, but I don't know if that helps me.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Take a solution $G$, and consider the field $G-G_0$. What is the curl of this field? What does that mean?

Comment: I tried this and got curl $G-G_0 = F - $curl $G_0$, but discarded it.

Comment: It seems like after applying this hint you'll still have to show $\nabla \times F = 0 \implies \exists f :\quad \nabla f = F$, which I'm not sure is much more obvious.

Comment: No, don't do that! Keep going. You already know what the curl of $G_0$ is.

Comment: As curl $G_0 = F$, then curl $(G-G_0) = 0_v$. Can I say that $G-G_0$ is a conservative vector field?

Comment: That's the idea

Comment: @WavilsonFerreira It has zero curl on a simply connected domain. So yes, you can. Just as you could say that $F$ was a solenoid field because it has zero divergence on a simply connected domain.

Comment: Right. So there is a scalar field $f$ such that $\nabla f = G-G_0$, hence, $G = G_0 + \nabla f$.

Comment: @WavilsonFerreira Exactly!